# $.now(); doesn't seem to be working in chrome on windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I wanted to use the $.now() along with the persons IP address as a type of random number generator to attach to the front of file names to insure that if a file with the same name was uploaded it would not overwrite the first one.
the code I came up with was as follows:

```
var ipadd = '';
var filename = 'name';
var militime = 't';
var uploadname = '';
var ipid = '';

$(window).load(function() {
  militime = $.now();
  console.log(militime);

  $('a.next-btn').on('click', function() {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
      ipadd = response.ip;
      ipid = ipadd + militime;
    }, "jsonp");
  });

  $('.file-uploader-form input[name="floor_plan_upload"]').live('change', function() {
    var filename = $('.flow-section input[name="floor_plan_upload"]').val().split('\\').pop();
    uploadname = ipid + filename;
    $('input[name="file_path"]').val(uploadname).change();
  });

});
```

I tested it in chrome on mac and it worked fine, it also works fine in firefox on windows but not chrome or microsoft edge on windows, it only displays the IP address.
Ive also tryed using Date.now(); and new Date().getTime(); to the same ends.

I did notice though that when I remove the militime = $.now(); from after the $(window).load(function(){ that it doesn't even print what I made the default value for militime 't', so that suggests that there is something else wrong here, I just don't know what.

Comment: is this the exact code?

Comment: Why would you accept input from the client to determine the file you create on the server?

Comment: there is also some code for the form, which is generated via script

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What debugging have you done?

Comment: there are no errors when the code runs, ive tried moving the variables around which only seems to break it for all clients

Comment: running jquery-1.7.1.js

Comment: Do more debugging. Where does the code stop doing what you expect it to do? Narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: Where you have `console.log(militime)` what value is output?

Comment: console.log(militime) outputs nothing at all, not even an undefined

Comment: You are using a lot of global variables. Are you sure there isn't other code somewhere else that's overwriting `militime`?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all your help, it turns out there was a larger issue here of my js file not updating, I got suspicious that none of my changes were having any effect, so I deleted the contents of the file and the form still ran as is i did not.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the user provided filename as the filename on the server. So, generate the unique filename on the server instead.

OK this doesn't solve the problem, but then again you're solving it wrong...

Comment: I dont have a lot of control of what is being generated on the server since we are using amazon servers, I need to pass it a name before it gets sent over.